# Android - How do you retrieve Week of Year from a onDateChangedListener?

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I'm building an application where I display the Day, Month, Year and Week Number from a DatePicker. When a date is selected, the date and the week number should then be displayed on screen. I've managed to display the correct date, but I struggle to display the Week Number

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.kalender);
    datoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kalenderText);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

    datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            String dato = dayOfMonth + " / " + (monthOfYear + 1) + " / " + year;
            datoText.setText(dato);
        }
    });
```

So, my question is this: How can I display the week number of the selected date?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn’t want to display the week number, you should use a formatter for formatting the date for display. That in turn will take nicely care of the week number too. I suggest you declare the formatter a constant in your class:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u 'Uke' w", Locale.forLanguageTag("no"));
```

Now the rest is pretty straightforward:

```
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        LocalDate dato = LocalDate.of(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
        datoText.setText(dato.format(DATE_FORMATTER));
    }
```

This will display a string like `2/4/2019 Uke 14`. You can tailor the format pattern string to the output you want. Letters that should not be interpreted as format pattern letters go inside single quotes (apostrophes), here for example `'Uke'`.

I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

If you you cannot afford an external dependency (even on a rock solid and future-proof library), the old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` can be used in a similar way, but only after you have converted the selected values first to a `Calendar` and then to a `Date`. Be warned, however, that the `SimpleDateFormat` class is notoriously troublesome and also not thread-safe.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.